# SharePoint Online: Recommended site type for page layouts

Tags: sharepoint-online, page-layout, spfx-webparts, design, modern-experience

We need **page layout**-like functionality in SharePoint Online and the current state of modern pages doesn't allow for the customization we need. Some columns and rows is fine, but we need fine-grained control over the layout including responsiveness above what is provided out of the box.

Now the question: is it supported to activate the Publishing Features in a **modern** site? (It certainly is technically possible but feels like a hack.)

Or should we go for a **classic** site, e.g. Publishing Portal, and use the page layouts there? Any drawbacks from this? We don't really need the latest and greatest modern features in this site apart from SPFx webparts and the "chrome" (ribbon, app launcher etc.).

We only need some fancy pages, the site is merely the container for those pages.